# lighttpd, absolute default index and broken getenv("SCRIPT_NAME")

Tags: php, indexing, lighttpd

For a directory index I set the default index file name to an absolute path in the lighttpd conf file:

```
index-file.names += ( "index.html", "index.php", "/_h5ai/server/php/index.php" )
```

Inside this `/_h5ai/server/php/index.php` script I try to find the URL to the script itself with

```
$path = getenv("SCRIPT_NAME");
```

This works fine in Apache httpd, nginx and Cherokee. They resolve it to something like `/_h5ai/server/php/index.php`. But lighttpd resolves it to the current URL, e.g. `/abc/`, plus this absolute path: `/abc//_h5ai/server/php/index.php`.

Any ideas how to fix this in lighttpd?

- see it in context: this is [the critical line](https://github.com/lrsjng/h5ai/blob/master/src/_h5ai/server/php/inc/init.php#L10) on GitHub
- the tool itself: it's [h5ai](http://larsjung.de/h5ai/), but the demo is served from Apache httpd

---

**update**

already tried PHP option `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1`, doesn't work :(

Comment: Maybe this bug applies your problem: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/729 - If so, try to use "fix-root-scriptname" in your lighty FCGI configuration.

Comment: thanks! but doesn't apply here..

Comment: isn't there also a SCRIPT_FILENAME member of ENV that holds a more useful value?  could you use that value's difference from DOCUMENT_ROOT to the get real URI of the script?

Comment: thank you, I'm using a similar approach for now.. but it still feels like a workaround/bugfix (only needed by lighttpd). but it works..

Comment: Could you post the specifics of how you solved it as an answer?  I'm in-particular, interested in how this applies to _h5ai

Comment: compare these two lines here: https://github.com/lrsjng/h5ai/blob/develop/src/_h5ai/server/php/index.php#L10-11 it's solved with a regular expression that replaces everything before a `//` (and including `//`) with a single `/`